# python mocking Fernet.encrypt

Tags: python, unit-testing, tox

I have a python script I need to add coverage to. I have 1 issue I am not able to resolve, The script need a JWT to make a request and uses a server key for the JWT.
The server key is encrypted and gets decrypted at runtime using Fernet package.
In practice, this works fine, but I am not able to mock the response from Fernet without putting in the actual decrypt phrase into the code (it lives as a env variable and tox does not have access to it).
this is the error i get
`raise InvalidToken cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken`

How can i mock this? here are the lines of code I am trying to mock

```
f = Fernet(self.decrypt_phrase)
    decrypted_data = f.decrypt(encrypted_data)
    with open(PATH", "wb") as file:
        file.write(decrypted_data)
```

It seems to get stuck on `decrypted_data = f.decrypt(encrypted_data)`

I tried to add it as a patch but maybe i am not doing that correctly, I am new to python and not sure how patch works

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple case of mock scenario. Perhaps you're having more difficulties with the mock concepts than with the Fernet per se. Take a look at the [mock documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html) for more info.

Here is a fully functional example with Fernet encrypt/decrypt functions.

```
import unittest 
from unittest.mock import patch

from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

def encrypt(key, text):
    return Fernet(key).encrypt(text)

def decrypt(key, text):
    return Fernet(key).decrypt(text)


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.key = Fernet.generate_key()
        self.token = encrypt(self.key, b"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76585653")

    def test_decrypt_should_succeed(self):
        with patch.object(Fernet, "decrypt", return_value="my_mocked_value"):
            message = decrypt(self.key, self.token)
        assert message == "my_mocked_value" 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```